# Activity indicator not showing up Android

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to show an activity indicator in my Xamarin app on Android. It is not showing up though. A lot of people have this problem but I can't find an answer.
I've tried it on 4 different phones and the only one it isn't working on is mine (All the same Android and API version).
My animations are turned on so that shouldn't be the problem.
Here's the code:

```
<ActivityIndicator Color="Red" IsRunning="True" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="True"/>
```

Comment: You need to show us the XAML. Did you try with emulators? Look through logcat, maybe there is something there

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll take a look at it in the morning. But to answer your question, yes I've tried it on emulators and it works there. It works on uwp as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently I didn't see that I turned my animation scaling off... I turned that to 1x and now it works.